# NavigationItem.BackButtonItem is null...?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I've pushed my View on to the NavigationController stack, I'm in the ViewLoaded, and I find that NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem is null. Why is that? How can I either disable it (temporarily, and I'd prefer not to hide it in this very particular case) and how could I consider renaming what it shows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Andrew said you can use

self.navigationItem.HidesBackButton = false;

to hide the Back Button and also you can use

NavigationItem SetHidesBackButton (false, true);

if you want to hide it with animation. But I want to tell you the part about

`NavigationItem.backBarButtonItem is null`.

Well the back button item that you see on the navigation bar belongs to previous view controller so thats why you are getting null.

And if you create a bar button item with some weird name and extra features(I dont know what else you can do with it.) and add it to your NavigationItem.backBarButtonItem it will be shown in the next view controller which is gonna be pushed on top of it.

That is the reason for your `NavigationItem.backBarButtonItem is null` part of your question.

Answer (score 4):

Apple recommends you set the Back button from the view controller you instantiate the new view from, and not in the `viewDidLoad` method.

This is how to do it:

```
SecondViewController secondView = new SecondViewController ("secondview");
UIBarButtonItem backButton = new UIBarButtonItem ("Title", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain);  // style, target and action will be overridden, regardless of value
NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem = backButton;
NavigationController.PushViewController (secondView, true);
```

Note that when creating a `backBarButtonItem`, only the title can be set, the other values will be overridden.

To explicitly disable the Back button:
`this.navigationItem.BackBarButtonItem = nil`

Comment: I've never seen code like that; with all the () and it just looks different.  Does it work like normal code

Comment: @Andrew It's because this is monotouch code. If you look at the edits, this is not the code I wrote. At all. The really annoying thing about it is that I don't understand this code, either. So, while it's true that the question was tagged for monotouch, I'm not sure how acceptable it is to completely replace an answer with an edit.

Comment: EDIT: rolled back answer to original

Comment: Yea, thats what I'm used to seeing when I program

Answer (score 3):

to hide the back button, use this:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
```

and then to show it again, use:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

you can set this hidden or shown at any point in your code; it doesn’t nexessarly have to be in `viewDidLoad`

to rename what the back button shows:

```
 UIBarButtonItem *clearAll = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash target:self action:@selector(trashMethod)];
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = clearAll;
```

and just like the back button, you can set this in any method, not just `viewDidLoad`

let me know if you need any more help

Comment: If you're replacing the back button, you should probably set `leftBarButtonItem`. It's also important to note that this new button won't look the same as the back button: it'll be a rectangle rather than an "arrow".